# Flutter bluetooth low energy: custom characteristic and service

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter-dependencies, android-bluetooth

I am very new to Flutter so maybe this is a silly question but I have been stucked for long time so I would like to have some help here. I am trying to develop an app for android which could connect to a bluetooth low energy device. This app will connect with an esp32 microcontroller which I am also programming. I would like to stablish communication between a mobile app and the microcontroler.

I have tried to achieve this by using the [bluetooth_low_energy: ^5.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_low_energy/example) library. I have tested the exampled showed and it works perfect! However, I would like to select my device and do not have to select the charasteristic nor the service.

I would like to have a button which would send data as a command for the esp32 or request it, making some change to the gui. Here are a couple of examples:

- Sending a 1 with a certain characteristic or service would set a gpio to 1
- Sending a 1 with a certain characteristic or service would get back data of a sensor

From my point of view, I should attach some characteristic and service to every button I would like to include in my app. I have tried to define the services and the characteristic as:

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                GattService customService = GattService(
                  uuid: parseUUID('0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'),
                  characteristics: [], // Agrega las características según sea necesario.
                );

                /* Definicion caracteristica */

                GattCharacteristic customCharacteristic = GattCharacteristic(
                    uuid: parseUUID('ffeeddcc-bbaa-9988-7766-554433221100'),
                    properties: [GattCharacteristicProperty.write],
                    descriptors: []);

                this.characteristic.value =
                    customCharacteristic; // Aqui se asigna la caracteristica que se quiere emplear
                final writeType = this.writeType.value;
                final canWrite = customCharacteristic.properties.contains(
                  GattCharacteristicProperty.write,
                );
                final canWriteWithoutResponse =
                    customCharacteristic.properties.contains(
                  GattCharacteristicProperty.writeWithoutResponse,
                );
                if (writeType == GattCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse &&
                    !canWrite &&
                    canWriteWithoutResponse) {
                  this.writeType.value =
                      GattCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse;
                }
                if (writeType == GattCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse &&
                    !canWriteWithoutResponse &&
                    canWrite) {
                  this.writeType.value =
                      GattCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse;
                }

                final value = await CentralManager.instance
                    .readCharacteristic(customCharacteristic);
                const type = LogType.read;
                final log = Log(type, value);
                logs.value = [...logs.value, log];
              },
              child: const Text('TEST BUTTON'),
            )
```

However, I am not able to make it work and I do not know how to fix it. Could somebody please help me with this problem?

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you [edit] your question to add more information about what exactly did not work for you? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: You can get list of services that are available on your connected BLE device and then you can subscribe with desired characteristic/service and communicate as per your requirement and for that you don't need to show it to user also.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan thank you very much for your reply! I would like to share this information but I don't know how to debug the app in order to get this information. In other projects I have done the debugging with Android Simulator software but since I need to use bluetooth I am building the .apk and installing it on the phone. By doing this I am not able to figure out what the problem is. Is there anything I can do to get more information? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @KaranMehta Thank you very much for your help! This looks interesting. How could I access the service and characteristic I need within the list? Is there any way to match the uuid I'm looking for with one in the list? How should I do it? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66773460/how-to-get-deviceservices-from-flutter-reactive-ble-example for examples of retrieving the services once you've connected. But note that the service you're talking about is the Device Information Service. Nothing about it is writable, so it's very unclear what you mean by "a button which would send a certain data." You cannot send data to the DIS. Each BLE profile and service has its own set of rules. They're generally documented at bluetooth.org, unless they're custom (which are very common).

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you very much for your answer! I will edit the post to provide more data to clarify the question.